# Deploy app through Google Play Store in a private channel without Google Apps?

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

I'm building an Android app which for various reasons **cannot be listed publicly** on the Google Play store.

I have found information about the [Google Play Private Channel](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en) but if I understand it correctly, this can only be used when all your users are within a Google Apps domain (which mine are not).

**Are there any similar methods that I could use to deploy my app (and get the benefit of easy installation for users, an updating mechanism etc.), or is my only option to publish an APK file manually?**

From what I can tell, manually publishing APK files is the only choice, but this seems strange to me since my situation must be common for "private" business applications.

In particular, I am concerned that it would look unprofessional to have to guide users through the process of turning on the "Allow installation of apps from unknown sources" setting.

Any advice welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would just deploy your app using Google Play "Beta testing and staged rollout":

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Your users have to join a Google Group or Google + community that you create so you can limit you audience and make the app non-public on Google Play but still allows your non-public users to update the app via Google Play instead of manual APK installation.

The only downside is that the members of the Google Group or Google + community will only be as private as their Google account provides. So, app users are known to each other but your app will not be public on Google Play.

Comment: @MattWilson what did you end up doing in this scenario? I have a similar situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can you not use BETA or ALPHA pushes

Comment: Interesting idea thank - I didn't know you could do that. Might be an option but it's not ideal since the app will never be available to the general public, and it wouldn't fill the users with confidence if the app is in a permanent "beta" state (even after version 1).